# Poetry or Poem Writing?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry

Any suggestion or guide for beginner willing to learn creative poem writing or poetry in Hindi and English.

thank you.

Comment: This question is extremely broad, and I've placed it on hold for now. Please see our site [tour], it will explain more about how this site works.

Comment: Thanks, Neil,

i got my answer. 

i never thought of reading poems can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to start writing poetry is to read poetry.  You have to understand what poetry is meant to do.  After you are well-versed in poetry then learn meter and the mechanics of poetry.  From there, remember, talent and mechanics only get you so far.  It takes a lot of editing, revising, and retooling to get the poem just right, or, at least as close to just right as the poem will let itself be.

Comment: Hey Bradley,

thanks for the reply. 

in addition to your help can you suggest me a few good books which i can refer as a beginner.

Comment: Of course.  Two great anthologies covering English poetry are [The Norton Anthology of Poetry](http://www.amazon.com/Norton-Anthology-Poetry-Margaret-Ferguson/dp/0393979202/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1436369846&sr=8-4&keywords=poetry+anthology) and [The Penguin Anthology of Twentieth-Century American Poetry](http://www.amazon.com/Penguin-Anthology-Twentieth-Century-American-Poetry/dp/0143121480/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1436369846&sr=8-5&keywords=poetry+anthology).  While I can't recommend them, as I haven't read them, Amazon does also offer a few Hindi poetry anthologies that may interest you.